# How to fetch record from multiple table with multiple ORDER BY mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables and i want to get records according to datetime for all tables,
Here is my table "users"

```
id      name
1       abc
2       xyz
```

Here is my table "paymentHistory"

```
id      bookingId           userId          createdOn
1       101                 1               2020-07-10 12:11:14
2       102                 1               2020-07-11 10:31:19 
3       105                 1               2020-07-11 12:31:19 
4       109                 2               2020-07-10 11:45:32
```

Here is my table "cancelPaymentHistory"

```
id      bookingId           userId          createdOn
1       103                 1               2020-07-07 11:31:28
2       100                 1               2020-07-11 14:31:28
3       109                 2               2020-07-08 19:28:41
```

Here is my table "usr_booking"

```
id      bookingId           userId          status          created_on
1       104                 1               Inprocess       2020-07-07 10:31:28
```

Now i want to get all record where userId='1' and according to createdOn (DESC) of three tables
How can i do this ? I want following result after query

```
id      bookingId           userId          createdOn
1       100                 1               2020-07-11 14:31:28      //datetime is in desending order( data coming from cancelPaymentHistory)
2       105                 1               2020-07-11 12:31:19      // data coming from paymenthistory
3       102                 1               2020-07-11 10:31:19      // data coming from paymentHistory
4       101                 1               2020-07-10  12:11:14     // data coming from paymenthistory 
...
```

I tried with following code but giving me empty result

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS sorted_data;

create view sorted_data as (SELECT bookingId, userId as user_id, userId,createdOn,createdOn as created_on, 'paymentHistory' as table_name FROM paymentHistory) 
UNION ALL (SELECT bookingId, userId as user_id, userId,createdOn,createdOn as created_on, 'cancelPaymentHistory' as table_name FROM cancelPaymentHistory ) 
UNION ALL (SELECT bookingId, user_id, user_id as userId ,created_on as createdOn,created_on, 'usr_booking' as table_name FROM usr_booking);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to correct view creation code:

```
 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS sorted_data;
    
    CREATE VIEW sorted_data 
    AS 
    (SELECT id, booking_id, user_id,created_on, 'paymentHistory' as table_name 
     FROM paymentHistory) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT id, booking_id, user_id, created_on, 'cancelPaymentHistory' as table_name 
     FROM cancelPaymentHistory ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT id, booking_id, user_id, created_on, 'usr_booking' as table_name 
    FROM usr_booking);
```

After executing this query you have view, and it's correct that this code return empty result - it's just creating view. But you need to make selection from it. Execute this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sorted_data
ORDER BY created_on
```

Result is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7e77108d633d73c7732f7d36430a6d9

But I think your structure is not optimal. It I were you I would made only three tables: `users`, `orders` and `order_states`. You will have only one table with all users' orders, states and all information you need you can get with simple SELECT.